# Set the x-position of a nav tab based on x-position of a max-width div with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I'd like to have the content of the nav to start at the beginning of a div which has a relative position:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    some content here
</div>
```

and with the css:

```
.content{
    max-width:60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RXQV4/1/

How to have the "Title" (.brand) to be at the same x-position than the beginning of content by keeping the background of the nav?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I re-explain what I want (not easy): I would like to have the .brand on the same bar which takes 100% of the screen; it should just push on the right the three tabs and this .brand should start at the same x-position than the .content. The problem is that I don't know how to have the information about the x-position of the .content (without jQuery if possible...).

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may [check this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rishikalia/6QPSV/1/)..

**Code**:

```
<div class="navbar">

    <div class="navbar-inner">
         <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <br />
<div class="navbar-inner yourTitle">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
</div>    
</div> 


<div class="content">
    some content here   
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.content {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 60%;
}
.yourTitle{
    width:65%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

Sorry, but this is what i understood from your post..

**Update**:

Check [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rishikalia/6QPSV/2/), if this is not what you desire than update your question with a screenshot..

Here's the updated fiddle screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Smart answer!